# exclude directories in webpack loader

Tags: webpack

I'm attempting to use css-modules in my webpack project but I'm also using some css from packages in `node_modules`. How do I write a loader(s) to only use modules in my `module` directory and not in the `node_modules` directory? I tried the following but it borks. It looks like it's trying to apply the modules stuff to the css in `node_modules`.

```
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    loader: 'style!css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
    include: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'modules')
    ]
  },
  { 
    test: /\.css$/, 
    loader: 'style!css',
    include: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')
    ]
  },
```

Comment: Does your `module` directory include a `node_modules` directory ? The answer about the `exclude` prop is correct, but your `include` should suffice.

Comment: my `modules` directory does not include a `node_modules` directory, it sits at the same level as `node_modules`

Comment: Then I admit it's confusing. Does adding `exclude: /node_modules/` to your first loader solve your problem ?

Comment: Then it's strange. There might be an undocumented behavior about using twice the same `test` condition…

Comment: You may also need to add an exclude field to your `tsconfig.json` .

Answer (score 5):

For those finding this now (like me), I got this to work by defining complementary `exclude` rules in my webpack config:

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  loader: 'css-loader',
  exclude: /my_app_client_dir/,
  query: {
    modules: true,
    localIdentName: '[local]' // no funny stuff with node_modules resources
  }
},
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  loader: 'css-loader',
  query: {
    modules: true,
    localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
  }
}
```

When writing this without exclude rules on *both* loaders, I got a compile error from webpack.

Comment: how to exclude multiple folder here...

`exclude: [
    /images/,
    /node_modules/
  ]`

I have used above code, but not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

From : https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#condition

webpack version used at the time was: `4.39.3`

```
            {
                test: /.(ts|tsx)?$/,
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                include: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend')],
                exclude: {
                    or: [
                        path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend/typings'),
                        path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend/data')
                    ]
                },
                options: {
                    // disable type checker - we will use it in fork plugin
                    transpileOnly: true
                }
            },
```

It is also possible to use `and`, `not` in addition to `or` as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

In order to completly exclude from the bundle, use the ignorePlugin (in this case webpack 5)

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
plugins: [
      new webpack.IgnorePlugin({ resourceRegExp: /yourRegex/ }),
    ],
```

Answer (score -1):

You can exclude the node_modules directory also:

```
{
    test: /\.css$/, 
    loader: 'style!css',
    exclude: /node_modules/,
}
```

Comment: how to exclude multiple folder here...

`exclude: [
    /images/,
    /node_modules/
  ]`

I have used above code, but not working for me